# Post-commit hook is not getting called for some commits

Tags: svn

We are using post-commit hook to copy the files from source to destination(source and destination are root folders of the repository).
folder . If property(property name : version) is applied on the any of the folder under the source , We called python script from the post-commit.bat to do the copy.

We are facing one issue while doing the copy , some of the folders are not copied from source to destination.
We found the issue by doing the follwoing Step ,
In the beginning of the python script we are logged the revision number and changed path to the log file for every commit. 
But for some two folders, there is no property set entry(revision number and changed path) in the log file. 
(Plese note that In the post-commit.bat, we just called the python script ,nothing else). 
When we tried at second time, the property entry of those two folders are available in the log file and files are successfully copied to the destination folder.

Is there any case for Post-Commit hook not getting called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post-commit hook should always be called, but it can fail for some reason and you may never know about it if the user who did the commit doesn't tell you. After all, as far as the user is concerned, the commit completed, they just got some error message that didn't mean very much.

Now, exctly what are you doing? Are you copying files from one Subversion directory to another, and then committing those changes? If so, how do you prevent your post-commit hook from firing the second time. If this is the case, it could be that your genius system to prevent the post-commit hook from firing in an infinite loop is causing problems.

Even if you're not doing this, creating a post-commit hook to do something that can take longer than a couple of seconds is not a good idea. A commit cannot finish until the post-commit hook finishes. If the post-commit hook takes 10 seconds to run, that's 10 seconds the user has to sit there wondering what is going on.

You are better off using a CI system such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to handle creating distributions for you. Jenkins is simple to setup, and will handle the post-commit for you without tying up the user's commit process in post-commit hell. If for some reason, the post-commit process *fails*, Jenkins can email to alert you of the issue. The Jenkins user interface is entirely web-based, and it's easy for developers to examine the history of your post-commit processes.